# Excel VBA\C# Programmaticatty hide +- buttons

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop

Excel's pivot table has '+-' buttons (collapse and expand) turned on by default.
Cannot figure out how to hide them in code (vba or C#, no matter).
I suspect this is global setting for PivotTable object, but i cannot find necessary property. Please help

```
PivotTable pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination: rngDes, TableName: "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion: XlPivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion14);
pTable.Format(XlPivotFormatType.xlReport2);
pTable.RowAxisLayout(XlLayoutRowType.xlTabularRow);
pTable.LayoutRowDefault = XlLayoutRowType.xlTabularRow;
pTable.InGridDropZones = false;
pTable.SmallGrid = false;
pTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight16";
ptable.???? = false; //How to disable +/-
```

Update
Thanks to @Slai, pTable.ShowDrillIndicators = true was exactly what i needed

Comment: Please add your code what you have tried. Your question should be [mcve]

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu, added code. In fact, it doesn't give any info

Comment: record a macro of hiding the buttons manually

Comment: `ptable.ShowDrillIndicators`. Easier to Record Macro in Excel and check the generated VBA code